# WebSphere Liberty AdminCenter - unable to manage collective members

Tags: websphere-liberty

I have successfully enabled the adminCenter feature in a collective but I am able to see only the collective's server configuration.  The admin center is not displaying the members' configuration.  Can someone tell me what may be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you view/edit the server configuration on a server using the Server Config tool in the Toobox of the Admin Center, the Server Config tool calls a REST API on that server under the cover.  In order for that API to work, a JDK/JRE must be found on the server by one of the following ways.

1. Specifying the --hostJavaHome parameter in collective updateHost command.
   e.g. 
   ./collective updateHost --host=[hostName] --user=[user] --password=[password] --port=[https_port]
   --hostWritePath=/liberty/wlp/usr/servers --hostJavaHome=/opt/ibm/java-i386-70
2. Create a link to java in /usr/bin.  e.g. /usr/bin/java -> /opt/ibm/java-i386-70/jre/bin/java
3. Add java to the PATH environment.  Exporting the PATH should be done in .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that the collective controller hasn't been setup with the right credentials to be able to connect to the host the collective member is running on. Certain operations (such as reading files, writing files, starting or stopping servers) require the collective controller to be able to execute commands on the target host. There isn't an easy way to view the host configuration  (which isn't great), what I usually do in this case is run the updateHost to ensure the credentials are set correctly. This can be done on the collective controller or the member.

```
collective updateHost <host name as registered with collective> 
   --host=<host of the collective controller> --port=<https port of the collective controller> 
   --user=<the admin center user> --password=<the admin center password> 
   --rpcUser=<a userid that can see/manage the collective member> --rpcUserPassword=<the password for the rpcUser>
```

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tagt_wlp_registerhost.html